# Disable/Enable <h:commandButton> on deselecting/selecting <h:selectBooleanCheckBox>

Tags: jsf, commandbutton

I want to disable the submit button on my jsp Page if the user has not agreed to the terms and conditions. I have tried many solutions available but still not getting through. Here is my code :

```
 <h:form id="form2" styleClass="align topLabel page">
 <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="check" onclick="document.getElementById('form2:saveForm').disable = !this.checked"/>Agree                 
                <li class="buttons ">
                    <div class="center">
                        <h:commandButton id="saveForm" styleClass="btTxt submit"
                            type="submit" value="Submit"
                            action="#{declarationFormBean.formSubmit }"></h:commandButton>
                    </div>
                </li>
</h:form>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

May the following code snippet help you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function checkClick(check) {
            document.getElementById('form2:saveForm').disabled = !check.checked; }
</script>

<h:form id="form2" >
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="check" onclick="checkClick(this)"/>Agree                 
        <li class="buttons ">
            <div class="center">
                <h:commandButton id="saveForm" styleClass="btTxt submit"
                                 type="submit" value="Submit" disabled="true" ></h:commandButton>
            </div>
        </li>
</h:form>
```

Also you could add required field. Check this : [RequiredCheckboxValidator](http://balusc.blogspot.in/2008/09/validate-required-checkbox.html#RequiredCheckboxValidator)

Answer (score 2):

Your button is always enabled on the server side, so correcting user-controlled code on the client side will still execute business action associated with the command button.

What you want is to disable button on the server by setting its `disabled` attribute to the inverse of the current checkbox value:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{agree}" ... />
<h:commandButton disabled="#{not agree.value}" ... />
```

What remains to be done is to submit the form either via ajax, by nesting `<f:ajax render="form:button" />`, or synchronously, by adding `onclick="document.getElementById('form').submit();"`. Both changes must be done to the `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox>` tag.

Comment: When I try to use <f:ajax> It shows me Unknown Tag. I am new to JSF so not completely getting your answer.

Comment: What JSF version are you using? JSF 1.x, or JSF 2.x? AJAX support was added in JSF 2.0+.

Comment: In my Project Facets I can see the JSF version as 2.2 still it's showing unknown tag.

Comment: Then you need to nest ajax tag in a following manner: `<h:selectBooleanCheckbox binding="#{agree}" ... ><f:ajax render="form:button" /></h:selectBooleanCheckbox>`.

Comment: I am doing this in JSP and not in Facelets. Any method in JSP by which it can work. I know it's deprecated but still need it for my application.